# Regex matching to a terminator plus a variable character sequence

Tags: php, regex, hex, preg-match-all, substring

Sorry to bother, I feel permanently lost when it comes to regex...

I have to match a string which occurs in a longer sequence of hex-values. My test-string is this:

```
BF1301020302000017BF1301030101010300FF6ABF130201010300FFC0BF1303010303030100FF98
```

Pattern is this:

- starts with BF13
- followed by an unknown amount of "01", "02" or "03" repetitions (\w\w)
- 00 marks the termination of the sequence between BF13 and 00
- after the 00-terminator, there are always 4 additional chars

I tried `BF13(\w\w)+?00(\w\w){1}` but it's obviously wrong.

The test-string is supposed to match and output these values:

- BF1301020302000017
- BF1301030101010300FF6A
- BF130201010300FFC0
- BF1303010303030100FF98

Thanks, guys!

Comment: Your pattern works, you just want `{2}` instead of `{1}` at the end because of _there are always 4 additional chars_. [Live test working here](https://regex101.com/r/SZcLDI/1)

Comment: Try this one `BF13(0[1-3])+00([0-9A-F]{4})`. Here you match `BF13` then `0(1 or 2 or 3)` 1 or more times, then `00` and then 0 to 9 or A to F (case sensitive) 4 times.

Comment: Argh! You're right @WashingtonGuedes. I forgot to switch to preg_match_all in phpliveregex... My bad! Thanks!!!

Comment: @Alex be careful with your Regex, you are accepting anything with `\w` instead of only `01`, `02`, or `03`, so it is not a "valid" regex.

Comment: Also, the capture group probably doesn't capture what you want it to. (Notice it captures `02` `17` for the first part and not `00` `17`, which would have been the last 2 bytes)

Comment: I don't know php, but I think the easiest solution would be to split by `BF13`, then for each item your value will be `"BF13" + item_value`

Comment: @Washington It is not a good idea to split here since there may be more chars after the item_value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one will do the job :

`BF13(?:0[123])+00[A-Z0-9]{4}`

**Explanation**

`BF13` BF13 literally

`(?:...)+` Followed by something (non capturing group) at least one time (`+`)

`0[123]` a zero followed by 1, 2 or 3

`00` Followed by 00

`[A-Z0-9]{4}` Followed by uppercase char or a digit 4 times

[RegExp Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4a31og/2)

**Sample PHP code** [Test online](https://repl.it/IXJj/1)

```
$re = '/BF13(?:0[123])+00[A-Z0-9]{4}/';
$str = 'BF1301020302000017BF1301030101010300FF6ABF130201010300FFC0BF1303010303030100FF98';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

foreach ($matches as $val) {
    echo "matched: " . $val[0] . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options:

Input:

```
$in = 'BF1301020302000017BF1301030101010300FF6ABF130201010300FFC0BF1303010303030100FF98';
```

Method #1 - [preg_match_all()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) ([Regex Pattern Explanation/Demo](https://regex101.com/r/95ZW1a/1)):

```
var_export(preg_match_all('/BF13(?:0[123])+0{2}[A-F0-9]{4}/', $in, $out) ? $out[0] : []);
// *my pattern is a couple of steps faster than stej4n's
// and doesn't make the mistake of putting commas in the character class
```

Method #2: - [preg_split()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) ([Regex Pattern Explanation/Demo](https://regex101.com/r/95ZW1a/2)):

```
var_export(preg_split('/0{2}[A-F0-9]{4}\K/', $in, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
// K moves the match starting point -- preserving all characters when splitting
// I prefer this method because it requires a small pattern and
// it returns an array, as opposed to true/false with a variable declaration
// Another pattern for preg_split() is just slightly slower, but needs less parameters:
// preg_split('/0{2}[A-F0-9]{4}\K(?!$)/', $in)
```

Output (either way):

```
array (
  0 => 'BF1301020302000017',
  1 => 'BF1301030101010300FF6A',
  2 => 'BF130201010300FFC0',
  3 => 'BF1303010303030100FF98',
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and explanations! This is really helpful to me while trying to improve my skills. The regex needs to work with preg_match_all since I'm parsing a binary and using a bunch of other expressions to find more stuff like this within my file. Anyways, great stuff! Thanks again!